# Why isn't this container running properly?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a container on Docker and I'm getting the following error message:

```
Successfully built 9df8ac137547
Successfully tagged ex-build-dev:latest
$ build-dev % docker container run -it -v "$(pwd):/app" -p 80:8000 --name python-server ex-build-dev
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"usr/local/bin/python\": stat usr/local/bin/python: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Here is my Dockerfile used to build the image:

```
FROM python:3.6
LABEL maintainer 'Martin'

RUN useradd www && \
    mkdir /app && \
    mkdir /log && \
    chown www /log

USER www
VOLUME /log
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["usr/local/bin/python"]
CMD ["run.py"]
```

Does anyone know isn't the `ENTRYPOINT` being recognized?

Comment: just remove `ENTRYPOINT ["usr/local/bin/python"]` you don't need any entrypoint to just run `run.py`

Comment: You're missing a `/` before `usr`. It should be an absolute path like `/usr`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `WORKDIR /app` together with `ENTRYPOINT ["usr/local/bin/python"]` and that ends up with executing:

```
/app/usr/local/bin/python
```

instead of:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Add absolute path to `ENTRYPOINT` directive, in your case: `/usr/local/bin/python`.